decode raydium transaction detail information
Solscan has introduced a new feature called "defi activities." By opening any token address, you can see all the transaction details for that token. Currently, I am using the WebSocket Subscriptions function, such as onProgramAccountChange and onLogs, to retrieve some data. For example, by using onLogs, I can get the transaction signature, and then I can directly retrieve the transaction details using connection.getParsedTransaction. By using onProgramAccountChange and decoding with LIQUIDITY_STATE_LAYOUT_V4.decode, I can get some token swap information. Is there a specific program ID I should listen to in order to directly retrieve detailed data like Solscan defi activities?

